# sqlite3 not connecting in VScode Python

Tags: sqlite

I have looked at the path, reloaded, added extensions for sqlite3, I keep everything in same directory, and have imported squlite3 and tried _sqlite3. When I write conn = sqlite3.connect() the connect never highlights like it does for everyone else in the tutorials I'm trying to follow... I have made mydb.db and sql.sql but it makes no difference, the sqlite3.connect() never highlights of works.

Extensions of sqlite3 in VScode, Path, reloaded, searched youtube, made files in same directory, etc. Yet conn.sqlite3.connect() is not recognized.